# Memory leak in PHP / Zend... seems to drain memory on every page load

Tags: php, performance, zend-framework, memory, doctrine

I run a site that is slowly but surely draining all of the available memory in Apache. Not sure how long it's been going on for - the server is set up to auto-reboot if the memory limit is reached, and the sysadmin has set up Apache so that the threads are recycled (I forget the exact details here... basically it stops the server dying when the memory is all used up).

Some tech specs:

- PHP 5.3.2
- Zend Framework 1.11.7
- Doctrine 2.0.2
- Twig 1.0.0-RC2
- Zwig (links Zend+Twig together)

What I've managed to find out:

- If I load a page on the website, the memory usage goes up - not dramatically, but if I go to another page the server hasn't freed up any memory from the previous request. However, if I simply reload the current page, it seems to be OK. I'm pulling the memory usage info from /proc/meminfo
- Working with the sysadmin, we don't think the cron jobs are to blame - the issue where the memory usage keeps going up occurs if you move between a few different pages, even with no cron jobs running at the time.
- I think the leak is occurring in $application->run(); within index.php.

Doctrine may be to blame, but I'm not 100% sure. Doctrine is run via the _initDoctrine method in the bootstrap. Some of the bits I'm using are as follows:

```
    $config = new Configuration;
    $arrayCache = new ArrayCache;

    $cache = new Doctrine\Common\Cache\MemcacheCache;
    $memcache = new Memcache;
    $memcache->connect('localhost', 11211);
    $cache->setMemcache($memcache);
    $cache->setNamespace("PDC_");
    \Zend_Registry::set("pdc_memcache", $cache);
    //$query->setResultCacheDriver($cache);

    $config->setMetadataCacheImpl($arrayCache);
    $config->setQueryCacheImpl($arrayCache);

    // Metadata Driver
    $driverImpl = $config->newDefaultAnnotationDriver(array(APPLICATION_PATH.'/Db/Entities'));
    $config->setMetadataDriverImpl($driverImpl);

    // Proxy configuration
    $config->setProxyDir(APPLICATION_PATH.'/Db/Proxies');
    $config->setProxyNamespace('Dpp\Proxies');
    //if (APPLICATION_ENV == "development") {
    $config->setAutoGenerateProxyClasses(true);
```

This is not the complete code - I've tried to include the parts that I thought might be useful.

Any ideas would be much appreciated... Thanks.

Comment: is PHP running as a fcgi module? How much ram have you got in the server?

Comment: Have you looked here? - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1145775/why-does-this-simple-php-script-leak-memory

Comment: WHat are you actually storing in the cache? And to what size is that limited?

Comment: Yes, quite certainly a cache problem. Memory growing after each request, not released, this is the job of the memcache thing, the fact you do not list memcache in the tech specs make me think you may have forgotten to buy some RAM for memcache :-)

Comment: @phpdev We have 4GB RAM. Will come back to you about fcgi.

Comment: Thanks for the replies, some comments: We have 4GB RAM. Will find out about fcgi. gc_enabled returns true. I will see if using __unset helps. Currently, not doing much with memcache - just some data that we load from the database. Where would I check or set the size limit? Is it possible that the memory could grow even if we're not doing much with memcache at this point? (sorry for double post, posting a comment to multiple people is not easy to do...)

Comment: I asked our sysadmin, he said we're not using fcgo, it's just running as normal mod-php.

Comment: If an answer helps, please vote it up, and/or accept it as a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apache with mod_php will obey the ['MaxRequestsPerChild' directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mpm_common.html#maxrequestsperchild) if required. This can restart the Apache/mod_php process after (say) 10,000 requests to clean up any memory leaks.  After that is in place, you can start some investigations as to exactly where the issue is happening, and so remove the problem. Something as simple as using [memory_get_usage()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.memory-get-usage.php) can be useful for that, or using Xdebug/XHprof for more widespread memory profiling.

Comment: Thank you, we did implement that to keep the server running at least. Will look into memory profiling. Have seen some improvements since we started caching some of the data that's being loaded on every page, hopefully we will see more improvements as we continue optimising.