# Why PHP doesn't clean completely the memory outside the function if I use objects instead arrays

Tags: php

I was testing the usage memory of a piece of code, using objects vs arrays, and I get this, that I can't understand.

I tried force the garbage collector, using gc_collect_cycles(), but doesn't have any effect.

This is the test using arrays:

```php
echo "Memory usage in the start: " . memory_get_usage() / 1000000 . " MB <br>";
$averageAge = getAverageAge();
echo "Memory usage outside function: " . memory_get_usage() / 1000000 . " MB <br>";

function getAverageAge()
{
    $people = [];
    for ($i = 0; $i < 1000000; $i++) {
        $people[] = ["name" => "Lucas", "age" => 21];
    }
    $averageAge = 0;
    foreach ($people as $person) {
        $averageAge += $person["age"];
    }
    echo "Memory usage inside function: " .  memory_get_usage() / 1000000 . " MB <br>";
    return $averageAge / count($people);
}
```

At the final, outside the function, the memory was totally cleaned ...

And, this is the test using objects:

```php
class Person
{

    public $name;
    public $age;

    public function __construct($name, $age)
    {
        $this->name = $name;
        $this->age = $age;
    }
}

echo "Memory usage in the start: " . memory_get_usage() / 1000000 . " MB <br>";
$averageAge = getAverageAge();
echo "Memory usage outside function: " . memory_get_usage() / 1000000 . " MB <br>";

function getAverageAge()
{
    $people = [];
    for ($i = 0; $i < 1000000; $i++) {
        $people[] = new Person("Lucas", 21);
    }
    $averageAge = 0;
    foreach ($people as $person) {
        $averageAge += $person->age;
    }
    echo "Memory usage inside function: " .  memory_get_usage() / 1000000 . " MB <br>";
    return $averageAge / count($people);
}
```

At the final, outside the function, the memory keep with 8MB, and I don't know why. If I left the scope of function, and I didn't returned
the object, why the memory was not completed cleaned?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/1145898/370321 If it does, add an answer to this question and mark this question as answered.

Comment: Thanks, @abelito this answer is pretty good, and make me to understand that the memory isn't leaking. But, I still don't understand why the memory isn't fully cleaned when I use objects, if the same code (but with arrays) is.